# How do I profile OpenMP offloading code compiled by clang

Tags: c++, clang, openmp, nsight

I am currently working with OpenMP offloading using LLVM/clang-16 (built from the github repository). Using the built-in profiling tools in clang (using environment variables such as `LIBOMPTARGET_PROFILE=profile.json` and `LIBOMPTARGET_INFO`) I was able to confirm that my code is executed on my GPU but when I try to profile the code using `nvprof` or `ncu` (from the NVIDIA Nsight tool suite) I get an error/warning stating, that the profiler did not detect any kernel launches:

```bash
> ncu ./saxpy
Time of kernel: 0.000004
==WARNING== No kernels were profiled.
==WARNING== Profiling kernels launched by child processes requires the --target-processes all option.
```

This is my test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdlib>

void saxpy(float a, float* x, float* y, int sz) {
    double t = 0.0;
    double tb, te;
    tb = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for map(to:x[0:sz]) map(tofrom:y[0:sz])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        y[i] = a * x[i] + y[i];
    }
}
    te = omp_get_wtime();
    t = te - tb;
    printf("Time of kernel: %lf\n", t);
}

int main() {
    auto x = (float*) malloc(1000 * sizeof(float));
    auto y = (float*) calloc(1000, sizeof(float));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
    }
    
    saxpy(42, x, y, 1000);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using the following command:

```bash
> clang++ -fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda main.cpp -o saxpy --cuda-path=/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.11/cuda/10.2 --offload-arch=sm_61 -fopenmp-offload-mandatory
```

What do I need to do to enable profiling? I have seen others using `ncu` for clang compiled OpenMP offloading code without additional steps but maybe I am completely missing something.

Comment: Could you try profiling the application using Nsight Systems to get an overall view of runtime? https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#openmp-trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the debug output generated when the program is executed with `LIBOMPTARGET_DEBUG=1` and after receiving help from other forums I was able to fix this issue. The program cannot find the necessary files of the OpenMP CUDA runtime library whenever it is started through `ncu` (or `nsys`).

A workaround is to add the path to those libraries to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (e.g. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/llvm/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

NVIDIA is now aware of this problem and are "looking into why that is the case".